# Tabularx environment

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have problems translating this table (from Online table generator) to `tabularx` environment so it would be coherent with the rest of Tables of my document. Could you kindly help me? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\hline
1                     & 2                    & 3                    & 4                    & 5                    & 6                    \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Pepe} & \multirow{2}{*}{a}   & \multirow{2}{*}{b}   & \multirow{2}{*}{c}   & \multirow{2}{*}{d}   & e                    \\
                      &                      &                      &                      &                      & f                    \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

That is, the table should start by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
\end{tabularx}
BLA, BLA, BLA.
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Remember, tabularx takes two arguments, you only listed one

Comment: Centering a box of `\textwidth`? Resize a a small table ? Multicolumns of 1 column? Another suggestion: Do no use table generators, the resulting code is garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two solutions. The first uses a `tabularx` environment, with all six columns using a centered version of the X column type. The second uses a `tabular*` environment, with all six columns using the `c` column type. Both solutions occupy the full width of the textblock.

Since `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}` does nothing at all, you might as well omit those instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\multirow{2}{*}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
% centered version of X column type:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
%%\centering  % <-- redundant
\caption{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{6}{C} @{}}
\toprule
1         & 2      & 3      & 4      & 5      & 6 \\
\midrule
\mr{Pepe} & \mr{a} & \mr{b} & \mr{c} & \mr{d} & e \\
          &        &        &        &        & f \\
\midrule
  &  &  &  &  &  \\ % no need for "\multicolumn{1}{l}{}" stuff
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1cm} %
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{tabular*}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{6}{c} }
\toprule
1         & 2      & 3      & 4      & 5      & 6 \\
\midrule
\mr{Pepe} & \mr{a} & \mr{b} & \mr{c} & \mr{d} & e \\
          &        &        &        &        & f \\
\midrule
  &  &  &  &  &  \\ % no need for "\multicolumn{1}{l}{}" stuff
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this very useful answer, Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

As @daleif mentioned you forgot to add the second bracket with your columns' specification `{cccccc}`.
Probably there is a reason why you want to use the tabularx environment from the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package.

> The pack­age de­fines an en­vi­ron­ment tab­u­larx, an ex­ten­sion of tab­u­lar which has an ad­di­tional col­umn des­ig­na­tor, X, which cre­ates a para­graph-like col­umn whose width au­to­mat­i­cally ex­pands so that the de­clared width of the en­vi­ron­ment is filled.
>   (Two X columns to­gether share out the avail­able space be­tween them, and so on.)

I guess you want to adapt the width of the first column as shown in the following example.

[image: Compiled output (using standalone class)]

I give you the according code as a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
% The [following] pack­age en­hances the qual­ity of ta­bles [...]
\usepackage{booktabs}
% Macro to simplify the code
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\multirow{2}{*}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{My caption}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{Xccccc}
\toprule
1         & 2      & 3      & 4      & 5      & 6 \\
\midrule
\mr{Pepe} & \mr{a} & \mr{b} & \mr{c} & \mr{d} & e \\
          &        &        &        &        & f \\
\midrule
  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

## Supplement

Additionally, keep in mind that there is [a package called tabu](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu), which is more powerful than tabularx.

Comment: It does not make any sense to use tabularx with no X columns, then you could just as well have used tabular

Comment: I agree with you, the package aim is to adapt the space between columns, e.g. `\begin{tabularx}{250pt}{|c|X|c|X|}...`

Answer (score 3):

You do not need multicolumns in every cell, nor `\multirow{2}{*}{...}`, nor `tabularx` or `tabular*` to extend the text width, nor empty rows. Here you have enough with `m` columns (of array package) and, of course, with `booktabs`: `:)`

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{My caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr\linewidth/6-2\tabcolsep}}
\begin{tabular}{CCCCCC}\toprule
1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\midrule
Pepe & a & b & c  & d &e\par f\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

By the way, I would not use columns of more two-three `em` here. Widening the table as much as possible instead of a small centered table does not make it more beautiful, but ugly scattered.